# Android: I can't fetch layout object by its id

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

This is xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

This is Java code:

```
View mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
// Or: LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
Log.d("LAYOUT", mainLayout == null ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL"); // Always prints null
```

The layout is always null.

Why is that? The id is correct, all other elements can be fetched without any problems.

Comment: The view must be inflated/created first in order for it to be accessible by findViewById(). Is this view visible (e.g. displayed on an activity) or do you need to get it outside of this context?

Comment: Not sure but i think u have to try clean build your project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you already attached it to the activity by using following code?

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling `findViewById()` straight only works if the view is currently visible via `setContentView(ID.OF.LAYOUT)` of the application.  Otherwise, you have to inflate the view yourself.  If you already have a view object, you can pull other views from it like this:

`View v = alreadyInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.idOfChildView);`

EDIT:

How to inflate a view:

```
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.idOfViewToInflate, null);
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I had to call setContentView before fetching the view. My 2nd day of Android programming :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your contentView from xml

```
setContentView(R.layout.main); //this will put it on the screen.
```